# Make an image change on hero direction, Simple 2D game

Tags: java

Hi every one i am having a bit of trouble with my java game, it is very simply made as i am new to java. and the game works fine well as good as i can achieve. But i am stuck on how i can change the images in real time. I am trying to figure out how to make my Monsters face me *"the hero frylark"* when they chase me. i have made 2 simple methods in my monster class. *left* and *right*  How could i apply these methods to make the image change **from** *image = getImage("/Game/images/police-right.png");* **to** *image = getImage("/Game/images/police-left.png");*. 
Oh and in my project library is golden_0_2_3.jar which contains some game engine stuff.

Please. 
Many thanks from edwin.

```
import com.golden.gamedev.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class MyGame extends Game {
// set the values
public Random random;
private Hero frylark;
private Monster[] monsters = new Monster[3];
private Token coin;
private GameBackGround grass;
private BufferedImage image;

public void initResources() {
    // set a new random number 
    random = new Random();
    // get the background image.
    image = getImage("/Game/images/background.png");
    // set the name "grass" to background and given the image from the image set above.
    grass = new GameBackGround("grass", image);
    // get the monsters image.
    image = getImage("/Game/images/police.png");
    // give the monsters their names "" and set them their image from the image set above.
    monsters[0] = new Monster("Monster", image);
    monsters[1] = new Monster("Monster2", image);
    monsters[2] = new Monster("Monster3", image);
    // get the tokens image.
    image = getImage("/Game/images/donut.png");
    // set the name "coin" for the token, then its x and y position, and set the image from the image set above.
    coin = new Token("coin", 400, 300, image);
    // get the heros image.
    image = getImage("/Game/images/snake.png");
    // set the name "frylark" for the hero, then his score "0" and lives "5". 
    frylark = new Hero("Frylark", 0, 5);

    //set the monsters random x and y positions.
    monsters[0].setX(random.nextInt(750));
    monsters[0].setY(random.nextInt(550));
    monsters[1].setX(random.nextInt(750));
    monsters[1].setY(random.nextInt(550));
    monsters[2].setX(random.nextInt(750));
    monsters[2].setY(random.nextInt(550));
}
// update method
public void update(long elapsedTime) {
    // Pause the hero "frylark" on hold of the space bar.
    if (!keyDown(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)){
    // if dead stop frylark moving on the 5 second game over sequence, being displays details and playing the game over sound. 
    if (Hero.dead(frylark)){
    if(keyDown(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT))
    {
         // Move left
         frylark.moveLeft();
    }
    if (keyDown(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT))
    {
         // Move right
         frylark.moveRight();
    }
    if (keyDown(KeyEvent.VK_UP))
    {
         // Move up on press of up key
         frylark.moveUp();
    }
    if (keyDown(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN))
    {
         // Move down on press of down key
         frylark.moveDown();
    }
    }
    if (keyDown(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE))
    {
         // Exit game  on press of esc key.
        System.exit(0);
    }
    }
    if (!keyDown(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE))
    {
        // Pause the monsters on hold of the space bar
        monsters[0].chase(frylark);
        monsters[1].chase(frylark);
        monsters[2].chase(frylark);
    }
    // if monster 0 has eaten frylark move to a random position and lose a life, plus play the lose life sound.
    if (monsters[0].eaten(frylark)) {
        monsters[0].setX(random.nextInt(750));
        monsters[0].setY(random.nextInt(550));
        frylark.loseLife();
        playSound("/Game/sounds/lost_a_life.wav");
    }
    // if monster 1 has eaten frylark move to a random position and lose a life, plus play the lose life sound.
    if (monsters[1].eaten(frylark)) {
        monsters[1].setX(random.nextInt(750));
        monsters[1].setY(random.nextInt(550));
        frylark.loseLife();
        playSound("/Game/sounds/lost_a_life.wav");
    }
    // if monster 2 has eaten frylark move to a random position and lose a life, plus play the lose life sound.
    if (monsters[2].eaten(frylark)) {
        monsters[2].setX(random.nextInt(750));
        monsters[2].setY(random.nextInt(550));
        frylark.loseLife();
        playSound("/Game/sounds/lost_a_life.wav");
    }
    // if coin is collected increase score and move to a random position, and play the coin collect sound.
    if (coin.collected(frylark)) {
        coin.setX (random.nextInt(750));
        coin.setY (random.nextInt(550));
        frylark.increaseScore();
        playSound("/Game/sounds/coin.wav");
    }


}

public void render(Graphics2D g) {
     // draw all the monsters, hero, and coin and background.
     g.drawImage(grass.getImage(),grass.getX(),grass.getY(),null);
     g.drawImage(monsters[0].getImage(), monsters[0].GetX(), monsters[0].GetY(), null);
     g.drawImage(monsters[1].getImage(), monsters[1].GetX(), monsters[1].GetY(), null);
     g.drawImage(monsters[2].getImage(), monsters[2].GetX(), monsters[2].GetY(), null);
     g.drawImage(image,frylark.getX(),frylark.getY(),null); 
     g.drawImage(coin.getImage(),coin.getX(),coin.getY(),null); 
     // if monster 0 overlaps another monster mover him back
     if (monsters[0].overlap(monsters)){
         monsters[0].x -=20;
         monsters[0].y -=70;
     }
    // if monster 1 overlaps another monster mover him back
     if (monsters[1].overlap(monsters)){
         monsters[1].x -=21;
         monsters[1].y -=70;
     }
    // if monster 2 overlaps another monster mover him back
     if (monsters[2].overlap(monsters)){
         monsters[2].x -=22;
         monsters[2].y -=70;
     }
     // draw the lives bar, and set the font colour and size
     g.setColor(Color.RED);
     g.setFont(new Font("default", Font.BOLD, 18));
     for (int i = 0; i < frylark.getLives(); i++) {
         g.fillRect( (i + 1) * 15, 10, 10, 10);
     }
     // draw the score
     g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
     g.drawString("Score: " + frylark.getScore(), 10, 50);
     // draw the level
     g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
     g.drawString("level: " + frylark.getScoreNum(), 10, 80);
     // game over sequence, changes the font to size 40 and displays game over, as well as the payers score and level reached plus the game over sound.
     if (frylark.getLives() ==0){
         g.setColor(Color.RED);
         g.setFont(new Font("override", Font.BOLD, 40));
         g.drawString("Game over !", 280, 290);
         playSound("/Game/sounds/game_over.wav");
         g.drawString("You reached Level " + frylark.getScoreNum() + "  Your Score: " + frylark.getScore(), 60, 330);
     }

}
// main method which after all classes have been read and checked, "Game development environment OK! " will be printed to the console.
// then a new game is created and given dimensions and launched.
public static void main(String args[]) {
System.out.println("Game development environment OK! ");
GameLoader gameLoader = new GameLoader();
MyGame myGame = new MyGame();
gameLoader.setup(myGame,new Dimension(800,600),false);
gameLoader.start();
}


}
```

and my Monster class

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

    public class Monster {
    private String name;
    int x;
    int y;
    private BufferedImage image;
    Random rand;

    public Monster (String nameIn, BufferedImage imageIn)
    {   
        name = nameIn;
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        image = imageIn;

    }


    public void chase(Hero hero) {
        if (hero.getX() < x) { // if hero is to the left
            x--;
        }

        if (hero.getX() > x) { // if hero is to the right
            x++ ;
        }

        if (hero.getY() < y) { // if hero is to the above
            y--;
        }

        if (hero.getY() > y) { // if hero is to the below
            y++;
        }

    }

     public boolean overlap(Monster monsters[]){
         if (monsters[0].x == monsters[1].x && monsters[0].y == monsters[1].y || monsters[0].x == monsters[2].x && monsters[0].y == monsters[2].y ||
                 monsters[1].x == monsters[0].x && monsters[1].y == monsters[0].y || monsters[1].x == monsters[2].x && monsters[1].y == monsters[2].y ||
                    monsters[2].x == monsters[0].x && monsters[2].y == monsters[0].y || monsters[2].x == monsters[1].x && monsters[2].y == monsters[1].y) {
             return true;
         }
         else{
        return false;
         }
     }


    public boolean eaten(Hero hero) {
        if (hero.getX() == x && hero.getY() == y) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public BufferedImage getImage() {
        return image;
    }


    public int GetX(){
        return x;
    }

    public int GetY(){
        return y;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setX(int xIn) {
        x = xIn;
    }

    public void setY(int yIn) {
        y = yIn;
    }

    public boolean left(Hero hero) {
        if (hero.getX() < x) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public boolean right(Hero hero) {
        if (hero.getX() > x) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your golden_0_2_3.jar ? Code you posted doesn't contain the assignment image = getImage("/Game/images/police-right.png"); that you have problem with so no one will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I would modify your Monster constructor to accept both images.  Then modify Monster.getImage() to call left() and return the correct one based on the result.  You probably don't need to call right() as well, since if the monster is not facing left then you know it needs to face right.  Unless you want to get more sophisticated and also add a view facing straight forward or backward.